# Should we delete DataLake Analytic Job after completion?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

We are submitting U-SQL jobs very frequently and we a see a list of jobs previously submitted in ADLA.

We see the total storage utilization of Data Lake store is increasing day by day. All of our jobs submitted only update one single output file and size is around 10 MB.

The current storage utilization of Data Lake store is 9.3 GB. We think it's due to the previous jobs resources are still saved in the Data Lake. Should we take care of this or we should do something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the job data expires after a couple of weeks, but if you are concerned and do not need the data for auditing or investigations, feel free to delete them.

Given that the store has no limit and the storage cost 4c/GB/month according to the current pricing website, it is not a big cost though.

Comment: Thanks Micheal , this info helps.

Comment: Hi Michael, in our case the job data doesn't expire. As a result the total storage utilization of the azure data lake shot up to 500GB and the total number of jobs is around 5000. So we want to clear up the old jobs, how can we do that? I don't see a delete button to delete a job.

Comment: @SarathRachuri:  Generally “Job Data” can be bucketed to “Job List” and “Job Resources”. “Job List” data takes up no space in the accounts and is not billed. Job Resources take up space but they expire in 30 days (some time ago this was changed from no expiry). 
If you'd like, please email me your account name (mrys at Microsoft) and we can take a look what the root cause is.

Also you can always delete the data in the job folder yourself after the job has completed (earlier deletion may not be advisable).

Answer (score 1):

You can go to /system/jobservice/jobs/usql/year/month/date.. Feel free to delete the folders that you don't need any more.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I deleted the specified folders and the total storage utilization dropped from 500GB to 100GB.