# Is it possible to delete a completed job from Azure Data Lake Analytics?

Tags: azure-data-lake

I have a lot of completed jobs piling up, so I would like to clean them up.

The answer to [Should we delete DataLake Analytic Job after completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003660/should-we-delete-datalake-analytic-job-after-completion) seems to indicate that it's possible to delete jobs, but I am unable to figure out how to do this.

I tried using the the "cancel" API but it returns `400 Bad Request`, saying it can't cancel the job because it has already completed.

Is it possible to delete a job after it has completed? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but not supported through the Job portal/tool (yet). Please file a request via http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

The way to delete it is that you go into the job folder in your ADLA's default ADL Storage, e.g., `adl://<youraccount>.azuredatalakestore.net/system/jobservice/jobs/Usql/` and navigate down to the date/time and find the folder with the job's guid and delete it.

Please note that the system automatically deletes your job folders after a while.